# What weather can I expect in February on Blackcomb Mountain near Whistler?

Tags: skiing, canada

My partner and I have only skied in Europe where we live. We have booked to ski in Whistler third weekend of February. All the weather reports seem to suggest that it will be relatively mild. Yet any weather reports for the Alpes are misleading at best. I am looking for some advice as to what would be a realistic expectation for temperature and wind out on the slopes.

Also what sort of layering/kit would be advisable for a pair of active forty-year-olds out skiing that time of year in Canada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What weather can I expect in February on Blackcomb Mountain near Whistler?**

Weather in February should be conducive for skiing in February.

I was up there last March and it was still quite cold although clear and not snowing. Every year may be different, but chances are you should be okay for skiing and not one of those warm years.

[Temperatures](https://www.whistlerblackcomb.com/explore-the-resort/activities-and-events/whistler-heli-skiing/plan-and-prepare/weather.aspx) based over the past ten years indicate lows of -12°C for Blackcomb and highs of -5°C

Fancy clothing is not really necessary, I wear a wool sweater and a water proof jacket, up there. Thermal underwear is a good idea too.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry overmuch.  I've skied up there about a dozen times over the years.  I can only recall one time that it was really quite cold at the summit.  -14-18 if I remember correctly.  Most of the time it is quite nice.  You can check seasonal averages for the town, at 800m altitude.  But then compare the immediate temp in town to summit temp to get an idea of diffs.  If it is really windy the lifts will get shut down anyway.

( It occurs to me that, living only 2 hours away, I tend to stay away when the weather is known to be bad for a day, so my experience may be more rosy than someone who flies in. Still, overall the weather is not very harsh).

(right now 12C difference Whistler summit to town)

https://whistler.weatherstats.ca/charts/

https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/british-columbia/whistler

https://www.whistlerblackcomb.com/the-mountain/mountain-conditions/snow-and-weather-report.aspx

can't seem to bring up a decent history from wunderground, keeps on putting me at Vancouver airport:

https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/ca/whistler/CYVR/date/2022-2

Pemberton is near to Whistler, although it has a bit of a microclimate.  Good average temp graph tho:

https://weatherspark.com/s/145247/3/Average-Winter-Weather-at-Pemberton-Automatic-Weather-Reporting-System-Canada#Figures-Temperature

Grab *waterproof* hardshells along with underlayers - maybe an extra set should you need to double-layer, which I doubt.  Std ski gear, really.  The town is very-well equipped with outfitters should you need to upgrade your cold weather gear.  At a considerable price, of course, Whistler being Whistler ;-)